# How to remove outdated trigger from QRTZ database?

Tags: java, spring, quartz-scheduler

I use quartz scheduler + spring. 
 Is there any way to remove out-of-date triggers from tables QRTZ_CRON_TRIGGERS.

For example earlier I had trigger `com.companyName.TriggerName` 
 than I renamed this trigger to `com.companyName.AnotherTriggerName`. 
 And now table QRTZ_CRON_TRIGGERS contains records `com.companyName.TriggerName` and `com.companyName.AnotherTriggerName`.

As a result I have exception

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'com.companyName.TriggerName' is defined.
```

Could anyone help me with this issue? Is there some way to remove such triggers automatically using power of quartz?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What type of JobStore do you have configured RAMStore or JDBCStore?

Comment: org.quartz.jobStore/class = org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreTX